# Как объяснить, что такое байткод?

Tags: c#, c, java, байткод, c++

Пытался объяснить начинающим инженерам, что такое байткод (в рамках пояснения принципов выполнения Java программ). Так вот, я пытаюсь стандартно объяснить, мол это что то между компиляцией и интерпретацией, типа каждая команда джавовского байт кода, это как несколько ассемблеровских комманд, но они смотрят на меня и говорят - не понятноооо! Они не программисты, не знают что такое ни компиляция, ни интерпретация, ни ассемблер, это я попытался на пальцах им объяснить, и вроде до них что-то дошло, а как можно на пальцах используя жизненные примеры объяснит принцип работы байткода?

Comment: Если они не программисты, то им это не нужно. Не тратьте время.

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_Java


http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4

Comment: Я сам не программист(по образованию), сейчас стоит вопрос проведения расчета охлаждения камеры сгорания ракетного двигателя. Так вот я хочу дать троим студентам эту задачу, на трех разных языках, и посмотреть у кого лучше получиться. Языки: java-среда эклипс, Си++ - Visual Studio и Visual Basic да еще и 6. Сам я его накидал в MathCAD и MathLab. Думаю должен получиться хороший эксперимент!

Comment: Извините за прямоту - но складывается ощушение, будто отвечающие, сами до конца не понимают, кроме @KoVadim что такое байт код. Не надо мразу минусовать! Вдумайтесь в вопросе было, что необходимо обяснить байт код, при условии понимания небольшого понятий компиляции и интерпретации! А у многих определения можно отнести как к первому, так ко второму и третьему!

Comment: Хотел было уже написать, но заглянул в [Википедию](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4) и понял, что ничего добавить не смогу.

@vanyamelikov, а Ваши коллеги эту статью читали?

Comment: @vanyamelikov Задание студентам на трёх языках (java, c++, vb). Да Вы, батенька, садист. Осторожнее по вечерам ходите в тёмных местах. А для таких задач, вероятно, лучше matlab (или клоны) и python.

Comment: @nitrocaster если они инженеры, программирование (и даже не основы, а как минимум полноценное владение микроконтроллерами, базовым Си, и чем-нибудь типа Python для своих расчетных программ) _обязательное_ требование

Comment: @nitrocaster даже базовый курс компиляторостроения в тему -- как минимум инженеру нужно умение набросать парсер любого текстового протокола на flex/bison/antlr/PLY (файлы данных в текстовом формате -- файлы САПР, АРМ, логи измерений со стендов, файлы конфигурации и данных чужих legacy программ), а для инженера-электронщика еще и написать ассемблер/микрокомпилятор для устройства на ПЛИС

Answer (score 24, accepted):

А нужно объяснять очень просто. Используя их положение. Для начала показываем этим инженерам программу на Java. Например, классический HelloWorld. И спрашиваем - понятно ли? Скорее всего они скажут нет. Объясняем, что и специальной программе, которая исполняет жава код, тоже не понятно. Для этого нужно "разобрать по косточкам".

Теперь делаем "псевдотрасляцию" - как для машинистки (секретарши). Для HelloWorld'а она будет такая.

- настроить окружение (в коде этого нет, но это автоматом) - приготовить бумагу, проверить катриджи.
- взять из памяти строку "привет мир".
- нижимая кнопки, побуквенно ввести сроку (здесь появился цикл:) ).
- почистить все за собой и отнести бумагу заказчику.

Формально - это и есть простой байткод. Только это человеческий байткод. А если в нем стандартизировать все операции и занумеровать, то все может быть сведено к набору чисел. Теперь к реальному байткоду перейти просто.

Легко будет объяснить и переносимость. Если человек (секретарша) выучит все коды операций, то она сможет выполнить любую работу, главное, что бы была последовательность кодов. А инженеры могут попробовать спаять-сконструировать устройство, которое будет это исполнять.

Comment: Прекрасный ответ! Особенно пример с машинисткой!)

Comment: ага, обычно это называют псевдо-код, проще объяснять сразу на программе-примере хелоВорд, но если у секретарши 4 размер - это можно все упростить.

Comment: По этой аналогии даже легко объяснить, что такое cloud. Это эникейщик, который имеет полный доступ к локальной сети и по мере надобности исправляет все. Его никто не видел (как и облако), но результат вроде есть и денежка куда то утекает:).

Comment: Ну, вообще байт-код явы может выполняться и на аппаратной платформе, но ведь машинным кодом он от этого не становится?

Comment: ну не аппаратный он код от этого.

Comment: Почему? Для конкретных платформ, где он выполняется на самом процессоре, он будет вполне машинным кодом. Правда, для остальных платформ он так же будет байт-кодом.

Comment: байт код или машинный код - зависит только от Вашего отношения к нему. Если глянуть глубже, то даже то, что многие называют "настоящим ассемблером и тру-машинным-кодом" (в данный момент я говорю о интелловских x86 и 64 битных процессорах, за другие не ручаюсь) по факту - также байткод, так как некоторые инструкции процессора внутри реализованы в виде микрокода. А современный процессор в некотором смысле этого слова - jit компилятор - все эти предсказания переходов,  перестановка инструкций.

Comment: @KoVadim, соглашусь - процессор вещь сложная и имеет свой микрокод. Ведь известно, что современные процессоры имеют снаружи CISC-интерфейс и внутри себя RISC-ядро. Так удается строить более высокопроизводительные микросхемы с использованием кучи прикольных технологий (переупорядочивание команд, спаривание команд, переименование регистров и пр.), чем если бы делать все по-старинке.

Comment: пример для псевдокода, для именно байткода есть еще важная вещь -- его машинное представление, для секретарши придется вводить десятичные опкоды, книгу памяти и таблицу трансляции команд на человеческий

Answer (score 7):

[[@vanyamelikov](/users/12322/vanyamelikov)](/users/12322/vanyamelikov) по-моему вы сами не понимаете что такое байткод Java :)

Байткод Java это машинные инструкции для несуществующей Java машины, которую часто называют Java Virtual Machine.

В чем сила брат? А сила брат в том, что вы пишете для некоей Java машины (когда-нибудь кто-нибудь сделает таки физическую Java машину). Что такое портабельность Java кода: это всего лишь вопрос реализации Java машины на какой-то реальной машине ну и т.д.

Comment: Изначально создатели байткода проектировали его как систему команд и рассчитывали на то, что будут созданы соостветствующие процессоры. И действительно, они были быстро созданы, но проиграли по экономическим соображениям. Оказалось дешевле использовать традиционные процессоры, используя перекомпиляцию байткода.

Comment: Изначально -- это когда? Байт-код и ему подобные решения появились задолго до java.

Comment: @rfq можно ссылку на физ.процессора напрямую понимающих байткоды Java?

Comment: @alexz имелось ввиду "создатели java-байткода"
@Barmaley https://www.google.com/search?q=java+bytecode+processor

Answer (score 4):

Я бы попытался объяснить как-то так:

Компьютеры "думают" простейшими инструкциями, и когда вы пишете программу допустим на С то она преобразуется в набор примитивных машинных инструкций.
Например было выражение на языке программирования

```
a = 42 * spam
```

Оно грубо говоря преобразуется в последовательность инструкций

```
достать значение из spam
умножить его с 42
положить результат в a
```

Так как компьютеры бывают разные то и инструкции которые они используют тоже не всегда одни и те же.

Поэтому придумали прослойку над этими самыми машинными инструкциями - байт код.
Ваш код написанный на таких языках как например java и python преобразуется сначала в него а потом уже в машинные инструкции. Зачем это нужно? Один и тот же байт код будет одинакого работать на разных компьютерах. Грубо говоря байт код это "обвёртка" над машинными инструкциями, повышающая переносимость программ.

Буду рад услашать критику по поводу подобного объяснения^_^

Comment: Спасибо отличный ответ! Многие дают ответы, по которым байткод, ничем не отличается от компиляции и интерпретации, чувство, что многие сами не чувствую отличия, и ртсылают меня на википедию, будто вокруг одни идиоты не знающие о ее существовании, хотелось услышать какого-то оригинального определения, а в итоге услышал несколько перефразировок стандартного! Не судите строго, но действительно складывается такое впечатление!

Comment: @vanyamelikov Пожалуйста, рад что вам понравилось^_^.В википедии что-то подобное конечно есть, но там всё написано слишком сложно (и поэтому разбираться по ней в новых для себя вещах проблематично). Не уверен что у меня получилось всё без ошибок объяснить. Вообще довольно сложно объяснять вещи так чтобы было просто и понятно.

Comment: @venyamelikov, просто надо **внимательно** читать Википедию:

     Программа на байт-коде обычно выполняется интерпретатором байт-кода (обычно он называется виртуальной машиной, поскольку подобен компьютеру)
     .....
     Байт-код называется так, потому что длина каждого кода операции — один байт, но длина кода команды различна.

Все остальное - это перефразировки именно этих фраз и обсасывание следствий (возможно для кого-то неочевидных) данного факта.

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, вопрос в том, как объяснить, что такое байт-код, не прибегая к объяснению остального контекста. Мне кажется, что не получится объяснить, что такое байт-код, не объяснив, что такое машинный язык и язык программирования, потому что он ведь не сам по себе, он прослойка между ними — т.е. чтобы понять, что делает прослойка, нужно понять, между чем она лежит.

Comment: Я же говорю многое они уже начинают понимать, сдвинулись от Hello World даже, они не безнадежны. Проблема в том, что они не понимают разницы. Говорят - а зачем байт код, когда есть компиляция(которую они надеюсь поняли!)

Comment: > Проблема в том, что они не понимают разницы.

У студентов интернет есть? Википедия их не забанила? Если они не безнадежны, то способны найти указанные в комментариях к вашему вопросу статьи.

Answer (score 1):

Самый лучший способ практический:

1. покажите основы программирования (примитивные типы, массивы, циклы, ввод/вывод)
2. пусть каждый напишет **эмулятор** некоей (виртуальной) ЭВМ: у каждого студента своя система команд, можете дать некий очень краткий обзор классов архитектур: стековая машина, RISC c 8-16 регистрами, CISC а-ля Z80 (команды регистр-аккумулятор и память-аккумулятор), 3хадресная машина типа память-память-память; гарвард/фоннейман (1 или 2 массива под код/данные). Заодно покажете понятия машинного кода, кодирования кода/данных, организацию памяти, ввода/вывода -- это все тоже входит в базовую программу обучения на тех.специальностях. И все это наглядно, можно GUI прикрутить, и даже в минимальном консольном варианте студент может добавить лог выполнения любой команды, или изменения памяти.
3. "А вот `машинный код` вашей `виртуальной ЭВМ` , который у вас хранится в массиве PROM -- и есть байт-код: все его отличие от машинного кода только то, что он выполняется не настоящим процессором, а вашей программой-интерпретатором. Ваша программа-интерпретатор -- `виртуальная машина`. Если вам интересно, в книге [DragonBook] вы можете найти алгоритмы и методы, как преобразовать ваш байт-код в настоящий машинный код и выполнить его на реальном процессоре -- этим занимается `JIT-компилятор` Java."
4. Байт-код также является `промежуточным представлением программы` [DragonBook] -- между программой на ЯВУ и машинным кодом. Так как при разработке языка Java предполагалось что Java-программы должны исполняться на любом компьютере с заранее неизвестным типом процессора, вместо компиляции (в машинный код) был выбран формат распространения программ в виде файлов с байт-кодом. Формат этого байт-кода, система команд и организация памяти стандартизированы, и описаны в спецификации `виртуальной машины JVM`. Также были написаны `реализации JVM` для распространенных компьютеров, например для ПК, и мобильных телефонов -- это программы, которые делают то же что делали вы: интерпретируют байт-код, а некоторые реализации умеют его компилировать в ОЗУ прямо в процессе выполнения байт-кода (JIT), что сильно повышает скорость выполнения программы.
5. Также было разработано несколько Java-процессоров, которые выполняют байт-код аппаратно, то есть для них он является машинным кодом. Но распространения они не получили, так как дешевле оказалось использовать широкораспространенные дешевые процессоры, JIT-компилятор и 100500 готовых библиотек (в т.ч. операционные системы), написанных на Си и Фортране.
6. А теперь берем п.2, ставим ANTLR, и пишем компилятор простого языка программирования (и показываете как парсить текстовые данные -- для инженеров штука необходимая, можно ассемблер написать в качестве курсовой)

Answer (score 0):

Байткод это система команд некоего процессора. Они знают, что у каждого процессора есть система команд? Программу на ассемблере для х86 видели? Если нет, то покажите. Затем, программу в *любой* системе команд можно исполнить аппаратно, можно программно (интерпретатором), а можно перевести в другую систему команд, и далее исполнить аппаратно, программно, или ... Так сложилось, что java-байткод интерпретируют или переводят, а х86 исполняют аппаратно. Но причины здесь экономические, а не принципиальные. Java-процессоры существуют, но мало распространены. На других планетах, может быть, все наоборот.

Answer (score -2):

Зачем придумали байт-код? В начале были интерпретаторы которые просто выполняли код из текста, но так как эффективность в постоянном разборе строк не есть хорошо, придумали работать с байтами, а не как с исходным кодом строк, то есть программа преобразует исходный синтаксис ЯП-а в байт-код где есть инструкции и метки и т.п. почти как в ASM, отсюда и происходит название виртуальная машина, а не интерпретатор, к примеру в Java это JVM. Так что тут всё просто, виртуальная машина при загрузке байт-кода исполняет его. Но это ещё не всё, для большей производительности ввели JIT, то есть компиляции байт-кода в нативный код на ходу исполнения, тем самым не много получаем конкурентоспособность программ к компилируемым ЯП-ам.